# AngularJS Show Content Conditionally By Expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a form which is being generated by AngularJs via a JSON object that returns an array of select names and values. The code is below and working well:

```
<div ng-cloak ng-repeat="site in form.json" class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">{{site.ItemName}}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option value="show-all">All</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in site['SelectList' + ($index + 1)]" value="{{item.SelectValue}}">{{item.SelectText}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

So it's currently generating two select drop downs from 1 JSON object being generated in the backend via PHP. I now need it to also generate some check boxes on the form so am adding these into the array generated by the PHP. The JSON for these will remain in the same format as for the current selects (select name, select value). The additonal data will be appended to the end of the current JSON object so I just need to make the div with class="col-md-6"> conditional. I have a value being returned into the expression {{site.ItemName}} which will be perfect for filtering this but I can't see how I can use this with ng-show to make this work. Ideally I need something like this on the current div:

```
  <div ng-show="{{site.ItemName}} !== 'checkboxes'" class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control select2">
      <option value="show-all">All</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in site['SelectList' + ($index + 1)]" value="{{item.SelectValue}}">{{item.SelectText}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And then the opposite on the new code for the checkboxes. I've tried the above but it isn't working. Thinking about it I will probably need another conditional on the actual ng-repeat so it doesn't action on the select drop-down HTML when we are looping through for the checkboxes.

Does this make sense? Or is it a crazy approach? Should I just create a separate app.controller and call to the api for the checkboxes? I'm trying to get all form HTML back in a single JSON object to avoid multiple calls.

Thanks,

Noon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-show` expects an expression , not interpolation

Try

```
ng-show="site.ItemName != 'checkboxes'"
```

Variables used will be evaluated within angular scope context

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.